# Reading racket code and interpreting in python3

Tags: python, racket

I want to understand what the code really translates into python3 as i cant follow along with it in racket. thank you!

```
(define set-equal?
  (lambda (s1 s2)
    (and (set-subset? s1 s2)
      (set-subset? s2 s1))))

(define set-subset?
  (lambda (s1 s2)
    (or (null? s1)
      (and (member (car s1) s2)
        (set-subset? (cdr s1) s2)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Racket expert, but I can at least read that code and figure out what it does.

Let's start with `set-subset?`.  This is a recursive function that takes two lists, `s1` and `s2`, and returns whether every item in `s1` is within `s2`.  This function works by returning whether `s1` is empty, or whether the first element of `s1` is a member of `s2` and the list of all elements in `s1` other than the first is a subset of `s2`.

`(null? s1)` returns whether the list `s1` is empty, `(car s1)` returns the first element of `s1` and `(cdr s1)` returns all elements of the list `s1` other than the first.

You could perhaps translate this into Python as

```py
def set_subset(s1, s2):
    return (not s1) or (s1[0] in s2 and set_subset(s1[1:], s2))
```

although this does assume that `s1` and `s2` are `list`s not `set`s.  (If `s1` is a set, you can't call `s1[0]` or `s1[1:]`.)

`set-equal?` builds on `set-subset?`: two sets are equal if both of them are a subset of each other.  Again, this would translate into Python as

```py
def set_equal(s1, s2):
    return set_subset(s1, s2) and set_subset(s2, s1)
```

These functions assume that the lists don't have any repeated values.

However, if you are using `set` objects in Python 3, you don't need either of these functions, as Python 3 already has these operations built in: `(set-subset? s1 s2)` in Racket is equivalent to `s1.issubset(s2)` in Python 3, and `(set-equal? s1 s2)` to `s1 == s2`.

Comment: FYI, Racket also has a built-in `subset?` predicate. In fact, there is [a lot of built-in set functionality](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sets.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply. This does work but if possible how could i make it so if i were to give this input: set_equal ([1,[2,[3,4]]],[[[4,3],2],1]), it would return true. And yes s1, and s2 is a list. i want to find the subsets of the lists and return true if it works and false. So something like: set-equal ( [1,[2,[3,4]]], [[4,3,2],1]]]] ) would be false.

Comment: @Bloodsucker: please ask a separate question for that.